# Kendo angular Readonly property

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am working on a web project with Kendo ui and angular. I have a pop up form, which I get when I click on edit option. I would like to make my pop up form uneditable based on my `discount` column. If the value of discount is `false` I should be able to edit the values on pop up window or else I should not be able to edit it.

This is my plunker url: http://plnkr.co/edit/yBTf4BbQB7xvQZyHRJXi?p=preview

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridEditFormComponent you get product model as input. You just need to check model value and disable/enable form:

```
@Input() public set model(product: Product) {
    this.editForm.reset(product);

    this.active = product !== undefined;

    // if(product) checks if product is not null or undefinded here
    if(product && product.Discontinued) {
      this.editForm.disable();
    }
    else {
      this.editForm.enable();
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cA7VzJnFWBFctSZlfrjm?p=preview